What would happen if a wife was declared dead but is actually living and wants to claim custody of her children?
If a woman left her family and was declared legally dead after seven years returns and wants to pick up her life with her remarried husband, and wants to see her children? What would she have to do to reclaim her identity?

A lot of this is going to depend on things such as why she was missing for 7 years that lead her to be declared dead in the first place.

This is a trope in movies and soap opera TV shows. Does it ever actually happen in real life?

That’s two very different questions. For the second, she would have to convince a relevant authority that she is the person who was declared dead after seven years. And then there’s a whole lot of mess to cleanup. For example, her and her husbands marital status. Unpaid debt or inheritance. Insurance payout. Most likely very country dependent.

@Barmar Being declared legally dead when you are not happens.

@Barmar I asked a related question some time ago, inspired by a book where a 30 year old woman is found freshly murdered and her father had been in jail for 14 years for murdering her at age sixteen, 14 years ago. IIRC there have actually been convicted murderers found innocent when their “victims” turned up alive years later. All over the world, so it would be very rare.

According to the wikipedia page linked above, some jurisdictions don't have any way to reverse a death declaration after some period of time. So she may have trouble just being declared alive, let along getting custody of her children.

It probably doesn't happen often enough that there's much legal precedent in any particular jurisdiction.

"some jurisdictions don't have any way to reverse a death declaration"  That brings up an interesting conundrum:  If legally dead, are you exempt from taxation?

@Barmar It is less common now than it used to be, but yes, it does happen. For example, on a trip to Wales that I took a couple of years ago, there was a late 19th century tombstone of a mariner who was declared dead when his ship was lost. He survived, however, and returned a decade later, forcing the tombstone to be corrected with hammer and chisel when he really died thirty or so years later, and leading to these kinds of complications.

@ohwilleke If the best example you can think of is from the 19th century, I rest my case. :)

@Barmar It is a convenience sample. There are other cases more recently, but that's the one most fresh in my mind.

@MichaelHall no: the taxman gets first bite of the deceased's estate. From outstanding income tax, and from inheritance tax.

@MichaelHall it might be rather convenient to work for cash as an undocumented person but might cause problems when wanting medical treament, etc. But I'd love to know on what grounds the not-deceased person thinks they are entitled to custody after 7 years absence and a remarriage.

Following some links, in some places it can be really difficult to become a legal living person again. You’d think it would be enough to show you are alive, and you are the person on a death certificate, but apparently not everywhere.

british-columbia
The first step would be for the person to apply under the Vital Statistics Act for cancellation of the certificate of death and correction of the register.
Then, as a parent, the person is by default a guardian of the child (Family Law Act, s. 39(1)) and

[u]nless an agreement or order allocates parental responsibilities differently, each child's guardian may exercise all parental responsibilities with respect to the child in consultation with the child's other guardians, unless consultation would be unreasonable or inappropriate in the circumstances

You haven't said that there would be any issues between the parties coming to an agreement relating to parenting responsibilities, but if any arose, either could apply to the court for a parenting order consistent with the best interests of the child.
If somehow parentage has been lost (e.g. by an adoption order to the father and the new spouse), the person may apply for a guardianship order to be added as a guardian. This application could even be with the support of the father and the new spouse. The court would decide the application consistent with the best interests of the child.

The new wife may have adopted the children. And the reason why the woman disappeared for seven years might play some role.

isn't a person that is officially dead by default unable to be a guardian?
